# How can i place these 2 in 2 different columns

Tags: html

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let person of check">
     <td>{{ person }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr *ngFor="let person of check2">
      <td>{{ person }}</td>
  </tr>
```

What can i do to keep these two in 2 different columns

Comment: keep the two td in the same tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing

```
table > tr of a1
        tr of a2
        tr of b1
        tr of b2
```

What you want

```
table > tr > td of a1, td of b1
        tr > td of a2, td of b2
        tr > td of a3, td of b3
```

Solution:

```
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of check;let index = index">
    <td>{{ person }}</td>
    <td>{{ check2[index] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me, and ur explanation was also good

Answer (score 1):

As `tr` is a "row" of your table, you simply need to put them in the same `tr`.

And, if you need to use your `*ngFor` tags in both of them, I suggest you tu put them on the `td`s:

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let person of check">{{ person }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let person of check2">{{ person }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The solution I was looking for was,list of check array in one column and list of check array 2 in another column, but this code has produced both the arrays in the same row. However @amit77309 solution worked